# How to perform face recognition on a streaming video using amazon Rekognition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-rekognition

I am streaming video the amazon kinesis from raspberry pi (This is done). Now i want to perform face detection/recognition on that video using amazon Rekognition how to do it explain in detail with links. Thanks

Comment: By the way, an alternative to using Amazon Rekognition is to do face recognition on the Raspberry Pi itself. See: [Raspberry Pi Face Recognition - PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/25/raspberry-pi-face-recognition/) (He has great articles!)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, i want to do it using AWS

Answer (score 0):

From [Working with Streaming Videos - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/streaming-video.html):

> You can use Amazon Rekognition Video to detect and recognize faces in streaming video. A typical use case is when you want to detect a known face in a video stream. Amazon Rekognition Video uses Amazon Kinesis Video Streams to receive and process a video stream. The analysis results are output from Amazon Rekognition Video to a Kinesis data stream and then read by your client application. Amazon Rekognition Video provides a stream processor (CreateStreamProcessor) that you can use to start and manage the analysis of streaming video.

[image: Amazon Rekognition streaming]

In simple terms, your application sends video to Amazon Kinesis Video. It then calls Amazon Rekognition on your behalf and detected faces are provided via an Amazon Kinesis stream. You can write an application to consume this stream and react to faces detected. There is a delay of several seconds for the video to be processed.